# Где в коде ошибка?

Tags: php

Где в коде ошибка?

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting (E_ALL);

?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="chat.css" type="text/css" />

<?php
echo ("<div id=\"block_chat\">");
echo ("<div class=\"comments_blok\">");

      $comments_file = array_reverse (file("/data/chat.dat"));

if(!$comments_file)
 echo ('<span style=" font-size:12px;">Нет записей.</span>');
else
{
foreach($comments_file as $line)
{
    $elem = explode('<!>',$line);

    echo("
    <div class=\"comments_name\"><span  class=\"mem_name\"><b>".$elem[2]."</b></span></div>
     <div class=\"comments_text\"><span  class=\"mem_texst\">".$elem[3]."</span></div>
     <div class=\"comments_dat\">". $elem[4]."</div>
     <div class=\"comments_par\"></div>
     ");

}
}
echo ("</div>");
echo ("</div>");

?>
```

На денвере нет, а когда выгрузил, хостиг показал

```
 Undefined offset
```

в этих строках

```
echo("
<div class=\"comments_name\"><span  class=\"mem_name\"><b>".$elem[2]."</b></span></div>
 <div class=\"comments_text\"><span  class=\"mem_texst\">".$elem[3]."</span></div>
 <div class=\"comments_dat\">". $elem[4]."</div>
 <div class=\"comments_par\"></div>
 ");
```

Comment: @Bridun, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Undefined offset означает, что вы вышли за пределы массива, проверьте входящие данные, выведите на экран массив при помощи функции print_r()

Comment: Приведите вывод  

    var_dump( $elem );

Хотя, увидев его, Вы сами все поймете.

Comment: Не пойму, выгрузил на другой хостинг - нет ошибки:

 Undefined offset это пустое значение.

Comment: Ну капец, такого еще не видел, я открываю этот код через фрем. 

А вот какая ошибка, видимо, это хостер.

Вас перенаправило сюда потому, что Ваш IP был заблокирован по причинам безопасности. Нажмите на правильную картинку и Ваш IP будет разблокирован. Вас перенаправит на сайт, который Вы пытались открыть.

Comment: Как можно бороться с этим?

Comment: Может, есть какие-то правила в хтачесе.